# What does % mean and do?

Tags: python

This is my first question here (yay!). This may seem like a silly question but in a if statement like the one below what does % mean?

```
    if n % i == 0:
        print("hi")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The '%' is the modulus operator. It's the remainder after integer division.

5/2 is 2 remainder 1. So 5%2 is 1.

In the specific case of comparing to zero, it checks divisibility. So n%i will be equal to zero if and only if n is evenly divisible by i.

Answer (score 3):

In the sample you mention it’s (most likely) the *modulo* operator. The value of `n % i` is the remainder after integral division of `n` by `i`. So, `n % i == 0` will be `True` iff `n` is divisible by `i`.

If `n` is a string, the `%` operator will do [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). This might not cause an error in your example code, but would still probably not have the intended result, and would be terribly bad form.

Answer (score 2):

This is the modulo operator. It is basically the remainder of n / i.

Answer (score 1):

This is the operator modulo.
http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Answer (score 0):

It's [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator, the remainder of the divison.